# How to loop through a string ArrayList and create temporary Character Arrays of each word in the String ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Lets say I have an `ArrayList` called `dictArray` that holds 5 words.  The five words are listed as so `{"aaron", "abates", "dog", "mellon", "zoo"}`.  I need to loop through this string ArrayList one word at a time, and for each word create a `ArrayList<Character> tempArray` to store only the unique characters within that word.  (I only need to go one word at a time because I will be performing calculations on the tempArray within the for loop). For example, each iteration would return the following:

`{a,r,o,n}`
`{a,b,t,e,s}`
`{d,o,g}`
`{m,e,l,o,n}`
`{z,o}`

This block of code will successfully store only the unique characters of the subject word:

```
 if(tempArray.contains(word.charAt(i))){
   } else {
      tempArray.add(word.charAt(i));
      }
  }
```

My question: How do I set up the for loop structure to go one word  at time, and then after identifying the word, go one letter at a time to call the above if statement?  Here is my current code but I am receiving the error message `type of expression must be an array type but resolved to ArrayList<String>` underneath all of the `j`'s.

```
ArrayList<String> dictArray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < dictArray.size(); i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < dictArray[j]; j++) {
        if(tempArray.contains(word.charAt(i))){
        } else {
            tempArray.add(word.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Arraylist != array

Comment: `dictArray[j]` -> `dictArray.get(j)`

Comment: @sleepToken thank you for the quick feedback.  It is now saying that ```j``` cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: `for (j = 0` -> `for (int j = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with a better format, and I will go down line by line.

```
ArrayList<String> dictArray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < dictArray.size(); i++) { 
    for (j = 0; j < dictArray[j]; j++) {
        if(tempArray.contains(word.charAt(i))){
        } else {
            tempArray.add(word.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Line 4: `for (j = 0; j < dictArray[j]; j++) {`, if you want to access an element in the ArrayList, use get(int index). Also, you should use dictArray.get(i) instead of j (which you did not initialize). i is the index of String in the ArrayList, while j should be the index of characters in the String.

Line 5 - 8: can be combined together. You want to add the character if it is not in the tempArray so you don't need to use an if-else statement. Also, you never initialized word, which I think you meant dictArray.get(i)

Last I think you want to add the tempArray to a new ArrayList (call it answer) of Array of Strings which contains the unique characters for each word.

So here is the modified code

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> answer = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dictArray.size(); i++) { 
    ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int j = 0; j < dictArray.get(i).length(); j++) {
        if(!tempArray.contains(dictArray.get(i).charAt(j))){
            tempArray.add(dictArray.get(i).charAt(j));
        }
    }
    answer.add(tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Wow @MT756 I really appreciate you taking the time to explain your answer!  As you can likely tell from my question, I am very new to java and this level of explanation is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> dictArray = Arrays.asList("aaron", "abates", "dog", "mellon", "zoo");
        List<List<Character>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        dictArray.stream().
                forEach(word -> {
                    List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
                        if (!charArray.contains(c)) {
                            charArray.add(c);
                        }
                    }
                    result.add(charArray);
                });
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

output :

```
[[a, r, o, n], [a, b, t, e, s], [d, o, g], [m, e, l, o, n], [z, o]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @amit3880 !  Did you mean to say ```List<List<Character>>``` or is that a typo?  I have never seen that syntax before

Comment: its list of list of charachers so its that way... .. you can run this class as it is and you should see the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for each to loop through the list and break the individuals down to char arrays and then loop through those

```
for (String s : arr ) {
            char[] cArray = s.toCharArray();
            for (char cs : cArray) {
                // Your Logic Here
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Victor Guazzi !

Answer (score -1):

`ArrayList`s need the `get()` method to extract a particular value. It might also be helpful to learn about the foreach lop, given here by `for(char c: tempArray)`. Basically, it means for every character given a variable name `c` in the list `tempArray`

```
for(int i = 0; i < dictArray.size(); i++)
{
    ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
    String val = dictArray.get(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < val.length(); j++)
    {  
        if(!tempArray.contains(val.charAt(j)))
        {
            tempArray.add(val.charAt(j));
        }
    }
    String word = "";
    for(char c: tempArray)
    {
        word += c;
    }
    dictArray.add(word);
}
```

This approach converts `tempArray` to a String `word` and stores it in `dictArray`

Comment: do you seriously add elements to a list inside the same loop in which you iterate through the same list ? Did you test your code to see if it even terminates ?